# kendo ui crud operations using only jquery and Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am developing a web application which deals with interactive grids. I am using Kendo UI for displaying grids and doing CRUD operations. I am new to Kendo UI.  We are performing database calls using jquery, Ajax only. I was able to make it read the data from the database and display it. But I am stuck at CRUD operations. How to get the event that a specific row or a specific single data is changed and perform the update. Please help me to understand how to do the crud operations. I couldn't find it in detail anywhere.  There are 8 parameters which are in the first column. The user should be able to change the rest of the data except the parameters.

following is the code for Grid.  CreateWBDGridData triggers the database service call and creates the table. gridSource is JSON data getting from the database after converting through Json convert function.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
var param ="HOLE_DIAMETER|4.875_CASING_ID|5.5_GRAVEL_PACK|NET_PERF_THICKNESS|PERF_DIAMETER|PERF_GRAVEL_PERM_@19k|GRAVEL_BETA_FACTOR_@19K|SHOT_DENSITY";
$.when(GetWBDGridDataByWell(param)).then(function (data) {
});
});

function CreateWBDGridData(gridSource) {
if (gridSource == undefined) return;
console.log(gridSource);
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        data: gridSource,
        schema: {
            model: {
                fields: {
                    ParameterName: { type: "string" },
                    Zone_1: { type: "number" },
                    Zone_2: { type: "number" },
                    Zone_3: { type: "number" },
                }
            }
        },
        //  pageSize: 20
    },
    //height: 550,
    //scrollable: true,
    //sortable: true,
    //filterable: true,
    //reorderable: true,
    resizable:true,
    //pageable: {
    // input: true,
    //numeric: false
    //},
    columns: [
        { field: "ParameterName", title: "Lucius 01", width: 300 },
        { field: "Zone_1", title: "Zone 1", width: 100 },
        { field: "Zone_2", title: "Zone 2", width: 100 },
        { field: "Zone_3", title: "Zone 3", width: 100 },
    ]
});
}
```

Controller

```
var dspstore = "System.Sources.Db.MsSql.DSPStore";

function GetWBDGridData(queryName, param) {
var varData = CreateParamQuery(dspstore, queryName, param);
CallService(GetWBDGridDataCompleted, varData);
}

var GetWBDGridDataCompleted = function (result) {
if (varDataType == "json") {
    var myItems = $.parseJSON(result.GetDataItemsResult);
    CreateWBDGridData(myItems);

}
}
```

Service call

```
function CallService(ServiceCompleted, varData) {
$.support.cors = true;
$.ajax({
    context: this,
    disableCaching: false,
    headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": '*',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    type: varType, //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb
    url: varUrl, // Location of the service
    data: varData, //Data sent to server
    //contentType: varContentType, // content type sent to server
    dataType: varDataType, //Expected data format from server
    processdata: varProcessData, //True or False
    success: function (msg) {//On Successfull service call
        ServiceCompleted(msg);
    },
    error: ServiceFailed// When Service call fails
});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, as I Understand there 8 parameters which are the first column, have had has 3 more items which user can edit if so do as below.

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
      transport: {
         read: function (options) {
             $.ajax({
                url: "/Your Controller/your read Action",
                dataType: "json",
                cache: false,
                success: function (result) {
                  options.success(result);
                },
                error: function (result) {
                  options.error(result);
                 }
               });
             },
        update: function (options) {
             $.ajax({
                url: "/Your Controller/your Update Action",
                dataType: "json",
                cache: false,
                data:{model:options.data.models},
                success: function (result) {
                  options.success(result);
                },
                error: function (result) {
                  options.error(result);
                 }
               });
             },
          parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
            if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
              return { models: kendo.stringify(options.models) };
              }
            }
          },
        schema: {
          model: {
            fields: {
             ParameterName: { type: "string",editable: false },
             Zone_1: { type: "number",editable: true, validation: { required: true } },
             Zone_2: { type: "number",editable: true, validation: { required: true } },
             Zone_3: { type: "number" ,editable: true, validation: { required: true }},
                }
            }
        },
         pageSize: 10
    },
    resizable:true,
    columns: [
        { field: "ParameterName", title: "Lucius 01", width: 300 },
        { field: "Zone_1", title: "Zone 1", width: 100 },
        { field: "Zone_2", title: "Zone 2", width: 100 },
        { field: "Zone_3", title: "Zone 3", width: 100 },
    ]
});
}
```

Use the model to specify the editable and non-editable fields and Your Data Source Data parameter does not use unless you're doing local calls, to do server calls call it as a function as shown above.

and your Controller action should look like below : (I Assume your using MVC)

```
 [HttpGet]
 public ActionResult ReadGridJson()
 {                
     return Json(yourlist, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }

 [HttpGet]
 public ActionResult UpdateGridJson(YourModelType model)
 {
     //update the DB and return the updated item
     return Json(updateItem, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }
```

Hope this helps, For more info check out the API DOC http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/grid